# My search query gets garbled

Tags: bug, search

When I enter this search

```
[java] [lombok] or [java] [performance] or [java] [performance] or [java] [garbage-collection]
```

it gets transformed into

```
[lombok] or [java] [performance] or [java] [performance] or [java] [java] [garbage-collection]
```

This is a bug. Not a critical one as `[lombok]` implies `[java]` anyway and doubling a term doesn't matter, but still a bug.

Comment: It is only an re-ordering issue, right? The OR tags comes first, all the AND tags last.

Comment: Thats a lot of java. Why not add some script?

Comment: It looks like the first `[java]` is moved to be in the last group of AND tags. This seems to happen in general, e.g. a search for [`[foo] [bar] or [baz] [out]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo+bar+or+baz+out) is transformed into [`[bar] or [baz] [foo] [out]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar+or+baz+foo+out). Try clicking the first link, focusing the search box and pressing enter. Interesting bug.

Comment: @AndréKool Needs [more jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/244695)

Comment: @rene It's re-ordering issue just like `2*3 + 2*5 -> 3 + 2*2*5` is an reordering issue. Maybe helpful when searching for anagrams...

Comment: Why do you have two `[java] [performance]`?

Comment: @user202729 Cause the field is too short and didn't see it. One should read `[optimization]`.

Comment: Way around would be manually manipulating URL to create proper query. If you are going to use that search quite often then bookmark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+lombok+or+java+performance+or+java+optimization+or+java+garbage-collection

Comment: @maaartinus Looks more like `[5, 2*5, 3*5, 4]` is getting reordered to `[2*5, 3*5, 5, 4]`; I don't see anything that would change results

Comment: [The advanced search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) gives no indication that ORing combined terms exists, it seems to only work with single tags on either side of the OR.

Comment: Actually scratch that, this appears to also be missing documentation and/or a mismatch between the intended functionality in the frontend and backend; @Pshemo's link returns a slightly different number of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now.... (30 chars)...